# Tracking down rogue terminal windows in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

I use iTerm 2 on OS X and suspect I may have a bunch of terminal windows running in the background and I would like to find and close them.

When I open a new terminal window my CL looks like this:

```
me@my-MacBook-Pro-16 ~ $
```

The number `16` is why I think I may have some unclosed terminal sessions somewhere. I may also just not understand what that number means, but when I start my computer it shows `15` and as I open new iTerm2 tabs, the number increments. Even when I restart the computer it starts at 15, is this normal?

If there are unclosed windows/sessions somewhere, I think they may be related to a brief period when I tried using `tmux`. I've looked around for commands to kill all tmux sessions and they report that there is no tmux session running.

I've gotten some strange `tried to access a mutex that's already running` errors with ruby processes lately which leads me to believe there something rogue running somewhere, but I have no idea how it could persist through computer reboots.

Comment: Please run the command  
  
`echo $PS1`  
  
and provide the output it shows on the next line.

Comment: \u@\h \w \[\e[0;36m\]$git_branch\[\e[0;31m\]$git_dirty\[\e[0m\]$

Comment: So you're no longer using tmux at all?

Comment: No, it is still on my system, but I am not using it.

Comment: Check you preferences. I'm showing there are options in there for tmux integration as well as options for closing out sessions on exiting a terminal.